# Update XMLTYPE in Oracle table with values from it's fields

Tags: oracle, ora-00933, xmltype

I have an existing table in an Oracle 10gR2 that I added a `XMLTYPE` column to it. Now, I need to fill this field with a XML that is composed with a mixture of values from the fields of each row, but I can't get the syntax down correctly. Below is the correctly working SELECT statement that generates the desired XML for each row:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("TBLOrigs",
  XMLELEMENT("TBLOrig", XMLATTRIBUTES(Field1 AS "Field1"),
  XMLFOREST(Field2 AS "Field2", Field3 AS "Field3", Field4 AS "Field4", Field5 AS "Field5"),
    XMLELEMENT("Dets",
    XMLFOREST(Field6, Field7 AS "Field7")))) AS XmlCol
  FROM TBLOrigin Orig1
WHERE Field1 <= 10
```

The UPDATE I'm trying is something like this, but it's not working:

```
UPDATE TBLOrigin
SET AUXFIELD = (
  SELECT XMLELEMENT("TBLOrigs",
  XMLELEMENT("TBLOrig", XMLATTRIBUTES(Field1 AS "Field1"),
  XMLFOREST(Field2 AS "Field2", Field3 AS "Field3", Field4 AS "Field4", Field5 AS "Field5"),
    XMLELEMENT("Dets",
    XMLFOREST(Field6, Field7 AS "Field7")))) AS XmlCol
  FROM TBLOrigin Orig1
  WHERE Orig1.Field1 = Orig2.Field1
  AND Orig1.Field2 = Orig2.Field2
  AND Orig1.Field3 = Orig2.Field3
  AND Orig1.Field4 = Orig2.Field4
  AND Orig1.Field5 = Orig2.Field5)
FROM TBLOrigin Orig2
WHERE Field1 <= 10
```

I'm trying to UPDATE each row with the XML content generated from it's fields. I keep getting the error below:

```
Erro na Linha de Comando:13 Coluna:47
Relatório de Erro:
Erro de SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Just as a reference, below is the working UPDATE in Transact Sql

```
UPDATE dbo.TBLOrigin
SET AuxInfo = (SELECT 
  Field1 as "@Field1",
  Field2 as "Field2", 
  Field3 as "Field3", 
  Field4 as "Field4", 
  Field5 as "Field5", 
  Field6 as "Dets/Field6", 
  Field7 as "Dets/Field7"
FROM dbo.TBLOrigin AS Orig1
WHERE Orig1.Field1 = Orig2.Field1
AND Orig1.Field2 = Orig2.Field2
AND Orig1.Field3 = Orig2.Field3
AND Orig1.Field4 = Orig2.Field4
AND Orig1.Field5 = Orig2.Field5
  FOR XML PATH('TBLOrig'), TYPE, ROOT('TBLOrigs'))
FROM dbo.TBLOrigin Orig2
```

Tks so much for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle doesn't do UPDATE...FROM

Does the following work ?

```
UPDATE TBLOrigin
SET AUXFIELD = 
       XMLELEMENT("TBLOrigs",
         XMLELEMENT("TBLOrig", XMLATTRIBUTES(Field1 AS "Field1"),
         XMLFOREST(Field2 AS "Field2", Field3 AS "Field3", 
                   Field4 AS "Field4", Field5 AS "Field5"),
         XMLELEMENT("Dets",
            XMLFOREST(Field6, Field7 AS "Field7")))) AS XmlCol
WHERE Field1 <= 10
```

If not, can you post the table definition.

Comment: Yeap... right on! A lot more simpler than TSQL syntax. Thanks so much!